# How to put a long title at the top without squeezing the figure?

Tags: python, matplotlib

[image]

In this figure, I have a long title at the top.

I want to fit the title without squeezing the figure (keep as a square).

Can we add space to the left and right while keeping the figure as square and title at the top?

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

title='A long sentence as a title'
fig= plt.figure(figsize=(12, 12), dpi=100)
plt.title(title, fontsize=75, pad=40, loc='center',fontweight='semibold')
plt.tick_params(axis='y', which='major', labelsize=75, width=3, length=10)
plt.tick_params(axis='y', which='minor', labelsize=75, width=3, length=10)

plt.style.use('ggplot')

ax = plt.gca()
ax.set_facecolor('white')
for edge_i in ['left']:
    ax.spines[edge_i].set_edgecolor("black")
    ax.spines[edge_i].set_linewidth(3)
    # This code draws line only between [0,1]
    ax.spines[edge_i].set_bounds(0, 1)

width = 0.9  # the width of the bars
x = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
y=[0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1.0]
plt.yticks(np.arange(0, 1.01, step=0.2))

plt.bar(x, y, width, color='violet', edgecolor="black", linewidth=3, zorder=1)

plt.ylim(-0.01, 1.01)

plt.tick_params(
    axis='x',  # changes apply to the x-axis
    which='both',  # both major and minor ticks are affected
    bottom=False,  # ticks along the bottom edge are off
    top=False,  # ticks along the top edge are off
    labelbottom=False)  # labels along the bottom edge are off

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work, to maintain the plot square but I (at least) don't see how to not compromise on the either 'title length' or 'font size' or 'figure size' and still achieve the end result you wish.

[image]

I have just added this below code snippet to your code to get the resulting figure

```py
box = ax.get_position()
print('Width and height before resizing: ', box.width, box.height)
offset = 0.05
box_dim = max(box.width * (1.0 - 2*offset), box.height * (1.0 - 2*offset))
# shift the box along x-axis and then resize to maintiain aspect ratio
ax.set_position([box.x0 + offset * box.width, box.y0, box_dim, box_dim])
box = ax.get_position()
print('Width and height after resizing: ', box.width, box.height)
```

Output

```
Width and height before resizing:  0.775 0.77
Width and height after resizing:  0.6975 0.6975
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not help. The title is still not seen. Is there a way to make it by changing the figure size maybe? The point is there are other similar figures, I want to keep the figure size and title fontsize same among other figure files.

Comment: Changing figuresize will do it, I didn't post that solution assuming you had a contraint on that too

Comment: Making the figuresize(16,16) works, but this time title will be smaller than other figures. I'm looking for a solution to add space to the left and right as extra space.

Comment: I'm not sure I can help with that. Maybe you can wait for anyone else to reply!

Answer (score 0):

You can tweak it by using `plt.text()` instead of `plt.title()`.

```
title='A long sentence as a title'
fig= plt.figure(figsize=(12, 12), dpi=100)
# plt.title(title, fontsize=75, pad=40, loc='center',fontweight='semibold')
plt.text(-5.5,1.1, title, fontsize=55, fontweight='semibold')
plt.tick_params(axis='y', which='major', labelsize=55, width=3, length=10)
plt.tick_params(axis='y', which='minor', labelsize=55, width=3, length=10)
```

[image]

Comment: Is not there a way to put space to the left and right so that we do not need to downsize the fontsize?

Comment: I modified the code with the understanding that the left and right margins are both sides of the graph. I also set the title text to the left.